# Rescuing an Ecto.ConstraintError to keep a migration rolling?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How do you rescue an Ecto.ConstraintError (caused by a uniqueness conflict - I have a unique index on a string property called "field")

Here is the code I have that is still raising the Error and doesn't seem to rescue - the ecto.migration stops:

```
    try do
      Repo.insert(model_changeset, on_conflict: :nothing)
    rescue
      e -> IO.puts(inspect e)
    end
```

One other thing to note - sometimes model_changeset is not a changeset but a struct - should I always pass a changeset? I assume with the rescue clause it wouldn't matter - I should be able to rescue any general error according to the way I specified it.

EDIT:

Here's the relevant error message:

```
%Ecto.ConstraintError{constraint: "cars_field_index", message: "constraint error when attempting to insert struct:\n\n    * unique: claims_name_index\n\nIf you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please\ncall unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper\nconstraint name. The changeset has not defined any constraint.\n", type: :unique}
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) transaction rolling back
```

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: @mudasobwa - added the constraint message

Comment: The error message is saying exactly what @MartinElvar proposed in the answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa, shouldn't I still be able to rescue/recover from the error though?  I thought rescuing a general exception means you don't need to add "unique_constraint" to convert the error into a status tuple....

Comment: eh... Indeed, one should be able to `rescue`. *confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a unique constraint to your changeset unique_constraint/3 (https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3), it basically turns the database error into a changeset error.

Then you can use a case statement.

```
case Repo.insert(model_changeset) do 
  {:ok, schema} -> schema 
  {:error, changeset} -> IO.inspect changeset
end
```

Comment: I have added a unique_constraint in the changeset, that is the puzzling thing

Comment: Can you post your changeset function, and your migration adding the constraint? :)

Comment: Hi Martin, if I recall right I think it's because I didn't have enough unique_constraint(s) in the changeset, so I'll mark yours as the answer.